# RandomizedSearchCV does not compue anything

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

so it's not my first time using RandomizedSearchCV but weirdly it stops computing, or at least it is not shown even though I set verbose = 2. It's weird cause it only fits the first 2 models and than stops or at least it never finishes and I don't see any progress.

The X_train shape is: (2037, 4005) (2nd degree features also included)

That's my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from scipy.stats import uniform
import random

param_grid = {
    'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
    'C': uniform(loc=0, scale=4), 
    'solver': ['liblinear', 'saga'],
    'max_iter': [10000, 15000, 20000, 25000] 
}

clf_test = LogisticRegression()

rs_clf = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=clf_test,
                        param_distributions=param_grid,
                        n_iter=20,
                        cv=5,
                        verbose=2)
rs_clf.fit(X_train, y_train);

# That's my Output: 

Fitting 5 folds for each of 20 candidates, totalling 100 fits
[CV] END C=2.7135152914205674, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=  14.4s
[CV] END C=2.7135152914205674, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=  14.0s
[CV] END C=2.7135152914205674, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=  14.3s
[CV] END C=2.7135152914205674, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=  13.5s
[CV] END C=2.7135152914205674, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=  14.7s
[CV] END C=1.2224168619608595, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=   7.0s
[CV] END C=1.2224168619608595, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=   7.1s
[CV] END C=1.2224168619608595, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=   7.6s
[CV] END C=1.2224168619608595, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=   7.0s
[CV] END C=1.2224168619608595, max_iter=25000, penalty=l1, 
solver=liblinear; total time=   7.4s
```

I tried to increase the memory storage from the jupyter notebook I run it on. But it did not help at all. Has somebody experienced the same issue or knows how to fix it.